# passing commandline arguments to a selenium python webdriver test case

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The following code is written using selenium python web driver which is run in saucelabs.I am providing the browser name,version and platform in a list,how do i do the same by providing the browser details through command line arguments? I am using py.test to execute the test cases.

```
import os
import sys
import httplib
import base64
import json
import new
import unittest
import sauceclient
from selenium import webdriver
from sauceclient import SauceClient

# it's best to remove the hardcoded defaults and always get these values
# from environment variables
USERNAME = os.environ.get('SAUCE_USERNAME', "ranjanprabhub")
ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY', "ecec4dd0-d8da-49b9-b719-17e2c43d0165")
sauce = SauceClient(USERNAME, ACCESS_KEY)

browsers = [{"platform": "Mac OS X 10.9",
             "browserName": "chrome",
             "version": ""},
           ]


def on_platforms(platforms):
    def decorator(base_class):
        module = sys.modules[base_class.__module__].__dict__
        for i, platform in enumerate(platforms):
            d = dict(base_class.__dict__)
            d['desired_capabilities'] = platform
            name = "%s_%s" % (base_class.__name__, i + 1)
            module[name] = new.classobj(name, (base_class,), d)
    return decorator


@on_platforms(browsers)
class SauceSampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.desired_capabilities['name'] = self.id()

        sauce_url = "http://%s:%s@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            desired_capabilities=self.desired_capabilities,
            command_executor=sauce_url % (USERNAME, ACCESS_KEY)
        )
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def test_sauce(self):
        self.driver.get('http://saucelabs.com/test/guinea-pig')
        assert "I am a page title - Sauce Labs" in self.driver.title
        comments = self.driver.find_element_by_id('comments')
        comments.send_keys('Hello! I am some example comments.'
                           ' I should be in the page after submitting the form')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('submit').click()

        commented = self.driver.find_element_by_id('your_comments')
        assert ('Your comments: Hello! I am some example comments.'
                ' I should be in the page after submitting the form'
                in commented.text)
        body = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body')
        assert 'I am some other page content' not in body.text
        self.driver.find_elements_by_link_text('i am a link')[0].click()
        body = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body')
        assert 'I am some other page content' in body.text

    def tearDown(self):
        print("Link to your job: https://saucelabs.com/jobs/%s" % self.driver.session_id)
        try:
            if sys.exc_info() == (None, None, None):
                sauce.jobs.update_job(self.driver.session_id, passed=True)
            else:
                sauce.jobs.update_job(self.driver.session_id, passed=False)
        finally:
            self.driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is a bit complicated because you can pass an array of browsers into the `@on_platforms` decorator. My solution will *only* work for a single browser, as it looks like that's what you're doing right now.

---

For the current, single browser, situation -- you're looking for **[argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)**. Here's my suggested fix:

```
import argparse

def setup_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Automation Testing!')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--platform', help='Platform for desired_caps', default='Mac OS X 10.9')    
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--browser-name', help='Browser Name for desired_caps', default='chrome')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', default='')

    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    return args

desired_caps = setup_parser()
browsers = [desired_caps]
print browsers
```

---

**But if you're looking to test multiple browsers** (which I suggest you do!), **you should not try and use command line arguments for the desired_caps of each individual browser**. You should instead  load a json config file for the browsers and the desired_caps for each one that you want Sauce to run.

Maybe have a different config file for each set of browsers, and then use command line arguments to pass in the config files you want to load.

---